# How I make a Laravel Authentication in a Third Party API that use oAuth2?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, oauth-2.0

I have an application in Laravel 5.7, I need authenticate the users in a other API (third party API), these API are code in REST with oAuth2.
So, I want send a username and password to the URL-API and the callback is if the user are or not authorized to use the APP.

How I can make this?

Comment: Did you ever crack this?